# How to append more rows to a Linq list after the condition is met

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which contains items (let assume 1000 items). I want to select data from that list where `TimeInSecond` matches the criteria.

```
newList = oldList.Where(x => x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90).ToList();  

// the above query returns 20 items (from 10 to 20)
```

However, I need to append next `N` number of rows from the `oldList`

```
// This is just an example of what I need, for example 10 next more items
newList = oldList.Where(x => x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90).GetNextMoreItems(10).ToList() ; 

// the above query returns (20 + 10) 30 items (from 1 to 30)
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you need. You take those items that match the `where` and then you just want some other 10 random ones too?

Comment: @GiladGreen that is right.

Comment: Presumably `GetNextMoreItems()` should return items which didn't satisfy the criteria?

Comment: @stuartd Right! It doesn't matter if the next N items meet the criteria,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned in the comments, you want `10` additional elements from the last element where condition is `true` (satisfied), you could do something like this.

```
// Get the elements where condition is satisfied.
newList = oldList
      .Where(x => x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90)  
      .ToList() ; 

// Find the index of last element and then take 10 elements from then on.
newList = newList.Concat(oldList
                         .Skip(oldList.ToList().IndexOf(newList.Last() + 1))
                         .Take(10))
                 .ToList();
```

Check sample [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yv0uHF) to see how it works.

Comment: this solution still adds the next 10 lines on top of the data where the condition meets, I need these 10 lines added after, the data received from the conditional statement

Comment: Ohh, so order is important for you. Let me edit this.

Comment: It doesn't work that way, it get the collection( where condition is true) and appends 10 elements of excluded elements).

Comment: Upon verification I noticed that it doesn't work exactly. It appends the next 10 items to the newList from the top of the oldList.

Comment: Gilad, to support his answer explained it well that first it takes items where the `where` condition fulfills  and then appends the next `N` number of items from the ´oldList´ in that order to the `newList`. But I like the simplicity of your solution, if it works that way :-)

Comment: None of the answers are working accurately. Did you have time to look back at your solution please?

Comment: You need to specify what is not working, are there are any undesired results? Please explain problem clearly.

Comment: The first iteration is different, suppose a list of 100 items, the where criteria meets from item 15-30, after that I want next 10 items to be appended to the result in order then the resulting list should contain items from `[15-40]`. In you solution there are two problems: 1. Only in the first iteration, Instead of "next" 10 items, it is adding first 10 items, resulting list having items from `[15-30&1-10]`. Then from 2nd iteration onward it takes items in right order i.e., `[30-45&46-55] `. 2. the list skips 10 previous items 1-10 or 46-55 from the next iteration from where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Union** or **AddRange** to append your new 10 items to your existing list. Of course, the data-types has to be the same. Here's an example with *int* type:

```
    List<int> l1 = new List<int>() {1,2,3 };
    List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 1,4,5,6};
    l1.AddRange(l2); // l1 now contains {1,2,3,1,4,5,6}
    // will remove duplicates  using default Equality Comparer
    var l3 = l1.Union(l2).ToList(); // contains {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

With your example, it may look like this:

```
var list1 = oldList.Where(x => x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90); 
var list2 = GetNextMoreItems(10).ToList(); 
var finalList = list1.AddRange(list2);
```

**Edit based on comment**
To exclude items that you've already selected, you can use **Except**, which is opposite of **Intersect** . So, for the *int* example above:

```
var l4 = l3.Except(l1); // contains {4,5,6}
```

And then, to pick certain number of elements, append **.Take(count)**.

Comment: I think you missed that he doesn't have `GetNextMoreItems` method and that is actually the question. how to do so

Comment: Thought OP was having problems with appending to an existing list. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those that match and `N` of which other items in the collection you can simply do:

1. Option 1: *where condition or counter*

   ```
   int n = 10;
   int counter = 0;
   var values = oldList.Where(x => (x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90) || 
                                   counter++ < n).ToList();
   ```
2. Option 2: *use a helping method to avoid repeating condition*

   ```
   Func<dynamic, bool> condition = (x) => x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90;

   var result = oldList.Where(x => condition(x))
                       .Concat(oldList.Where(x => !condition(x)).Take(n));
   ```

---

**If order matters** and you want to take `N` items that come **only after** all those that match:

1. Option 1:

   ```
   int n = 10;
   var values = oldList.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                       .Where(x => x.item.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.item.TimeInSecond <= 90);

   var lastItem = values.Max(item => item.index);

   var result = values.Select(item => item.item)
                      .Concat(oldList.Skip(lastItem + 1).ToList().Take(n));
   ```
2. Option 2: *Maybe looks a bit cleaner.. not sure (and has to have the `ToList()` just before the concat*:

   ```
   int n = 1;
   int lastItem = 0;

   var result = oldList.Where((x, i) =>
                       {
                           var outcome = x.TimeInSecond >= 30 && x.TimeInSecond <= 90;
                           if (outcome)
                               lastItem = i;

                           return outcome;
                       }).ToList()
                       .Concat(oldList.Skip(lastItem + 1).ToList().Take(n)); //Result: 40, 50, 100 (from data below)
   ```

Tested with:

```
List<dynamic> oldList = new List<dynamic>()
{
    new {TimeInSecond = 10},
    new {TimeInSecond = 40},
    new {TimeInSecond = 50},
    new {TimeInSecond = 100},
    new {TimeInSecond = 120},
};
```

Comment: Thanks Gilad. However the Option2 is returning only 10 items. Option1 is giving some errors that IEnumerable cannot be converted to the list. I didn't debug the Option1 yet.

Comment: @wafers - Which of the Option2? in the section where order matters? I've just ran it (added test data) and it returned 40,50 (condition matched), 100 (n = 1)

Comment: Hmm.. there was something strange that I received only 10 items, however Option2 is working now. Returning exactly what I want. Thanks! (Option1 is not thoroughly tested by me)

Comment: @wafers - I don't understand if you want to take 10 items that come after those in the where (meaning after in the list, a grater index value) or just 10 values from anywhere but append them to the end of the list (if that is the case see top section, option1)

Comment: 10 number right after the `where` condition is met. Exactly the way you have explained your example above. First it gets the items from the list "40" and "50" then it appends next `N` number of items, if `N=2` then the list should have items with timesInSecond "40", "50", "100" and "120", and in this order.

Comment: @So if I understand correctly you want the `N` that come after the index of the last item from the `where` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121731/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-wafers).